# SASS Color Theme without repeat elements

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to create themes with many colors using sass, but all examples I saw I have to replicate blocks of CSS using different variable names. What I want is use same name variables on different classes colors.

What I have in my mind is something like this.

```
//
// My regular CSS
//
.header
    background-color: $color1
    border-color: $color2

.menu
    background-color: $color2
    border-color: $color1


//
// My colors.sass could be like this
//
.color-green
  $color1: green
  $color2: red

.color-blue
  $color1: blue
  $color2: orange
```

What I think the compile would give me:

```
.color-green .header
    background-color: green
    border-color: red

.color-blue .header
    background-color: blue
    border-color: orange

.color-green .menu
    background-color: red
    border-color: green

.color-green .menu
    background-color: orange
    border-color: blue
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same need a few days ago. And I found out that in Sass, you can have a multidimensional list, so instead of constructing individual variables, you'd create one variable to hold them all, then loop over them:

```
$themes: news #f44f74 #f497ac, sports #5cbb00 #b2e581, entertainment #00afc4 #92d3db 

@each $theme in $themes
  $area: nth($theme, 1)
  $colorA: nth($theme, 2)
  $colorB: nth($theme, 3)

  //you can use apply a class to the body so you can customize everything else easily
  div.#{$area}
    h1
      color: $colorA
      border-bottom: 2px solid $colorB
    p
      color: desaturate($colorA, 60%)
```

**Have a look on this example I prepared on Codepen: http://codepen.io/renatocarvalho/pen/CxcEJ**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need too, then i write a loader for webpack to resolve such problem, you could check out the [DEMO](https://nothinggift.github.io/sass-themes-loader/) to see how it works, just like you expect .

This loader compile sass with different theme variables, you can register theme by sass files and javascript.

you'd create a theme folder like this:

- themes

  - theme-a.scss
  - theme-b.scss
  - theme-c.scss

and set webpack config:

```
// webpack1
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!sass-themes-loader'
    }
  ]
},
'sassThemes': {
  themePath: "absolute path of theme folder",
  //defaultTheme: "default theme name",
  //excludeTheme: ["themeName", "themeName"],
  //only: ["path of sass file"]
}
```

and then if you import a sass file,it will automatic themed:

```
div {
  color: $text-color;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

will be:

```
div {
  color: $text-color;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.theme-a div {
  color: 'color-a'
}
.theme-b div {
  color: 'color-b'
}
.theme-c div {
  color: 'color-c'
}
```

for more usage,you should check out [DEMO](https://nothinggift.github.io/sass-themes-loader/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a different assignment to the same variables ($color1 and $color2) with a simple if statement, checking the value of an extra variable, e.g.

```
$theme: light;

  @if $theme == light {

    $color1: green;
    $color2: red;

  } 
  @else if $type == dark {

    $color1: blue;
    $color2: orange;

  } 
  @else {
     /* fallback values */
  }
```

and for scalability I just suggest to wrap this code in a `themes.scss` file, and to include it at the beginning of your main sass file. When you want to change theme, just change the value of your `$theme` variable.

You can find further info about [the @if directive](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id10) on the official site

Comment: I change the theme putting an variable on HTML element. If the theme need to be green, I write this: <html class="color-green">

Change theme changing the value of variable in SASS is not possible to me.

Comment: With this approach I'm just changing the colours only on compiling time

Comment: Understand.

We serve a framework. We need compile all colors. In this way the user can be change the color when he need changing class in HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

I think sass mixins are the answer here.

Imo, the best way to do this is to create mixin called ex. generate_theme, and pass color as a parameter.

Something like this: [note: I use scss syntax]

```
@mixin generate_theme ($name: 'green', $color: green) { // pass as many colors you need...
    .color-#{$name} .header {
        background-color: $color;
    }
    .color-#{$name} .menu {
        background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

So this mixin has two parameters, but it could have more (like color palette I think?), and it has some default values (green). Parameter $name can be useful if you want to use hex values (classes like .color-#000322 wouldn't be very maintainable).

So then you just have to include your mixin like this:

```
@include generate_theme; // default colors
@include generate_theme('oceanlike', #000000);
```

so output will be:

```
.color-green .header {
  background-color: green;
}

.color-green .menu {
  background-color: green;
}

.color-oceanlike .header {
  background-color: black;
}

.color-oceanlike .menu {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't run of duplicate some code. Here is the Github with the code:
https://github.com/locaweb/locawebstyle/tree/v2/source/assets/stylesheets/locastyle/layout/colors

Here is the solution explained:

I create a shared.sass, where I put all elements that I need to change the colors, example:

**shared.sass**

```
#{$theme-color}

    body {
      background-color: $color2;
    }

    p {
      color: $color1;
    }
```

And I create other files with the name of colours that I apply. This files will have the pallete of colors in variables, like this:

**green.sass**

```
$theme-color: ".color-green"

$color1: #000
$color2: #FFF
...

@import "shared"
```

And a **colors.sass** importing all files:

```
@import "green"
@import "shared"
```

What you think guys?